# Why is it so easy to write a Multivariate Normal Distribution but not a Multivariate Exponential?

Tags: probability

For a N Variables, here is the multivariate Normal Distribution:

\begin{align*}
x_1 &\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_1, \sigma_1^2) \\
x_2 &\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_2, \sigma_2^2) \\
&\vdots \\
x_n &\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_n, \sigma_n^2) \\
\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{bmatrix} &\sim \mathcal{N}\left(\begin{bmatrix} \mu_1 \\ \mu_2 \\ \vdots \\ \mu_n \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} \sigma_1^2 & \sigma_{12} & \cdots & \sigma_{1n} \\ \sigma_{21} & \sigma_2^2 & \cdots & \sigma_{2n} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ \sigma_{n1} & \sigma_{n2} & \cdots & \sigma_n^2 \end{bmatrix}\right)
\end{align*}

If I had many Exponential random variables (variance of a exponential random variable $x_i$ ~ $exp(\lambda_i)$ is ${1}/{\lambda_i}$):

\begin{align*}
X_1 &\sim \text{Exp}(\lambda_1) \\
X_2 &\sim \text{Exp}(\lambda_2) \\
&\vdots \\
X_n &\sim \text{Exp}(\lambda_n)
\end{align*}

How come we can't write:

\begin{align*}
X_1 &\sim \text{Exp}(\lambda_1) \\
X_2 &\sim \text{Exp}(\lambda_2) \\
&\vdots \\
X_n &\sim \text{Exp}(\lambda_n) \\
\begin{bmatrix} X_1 \\ X_2 \\ \vdots \\ X_n \end{bmatrix} &\sim \text{Exp}\left(\begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1 \\ \lambda_2 \\ \vdots \\ \lambda_n \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{\lambda_1^2} & \sigma_{12} & \cdots & \sigma_{1n} \\ \sigma_{21} & \frac{1}{\lambda_2^2} & \cdots & \sigma_{2n} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ \sigma_{n1} & \sigma_{n2} & \cdots & \frac{1}{\lambda_n^2} \end{bmatrix}\right)
\end{align*}

And this links shows us how to calculate the covariance of two exponential variables: [Finding covariance from exponential distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4101399/finding-covariance-from-exponential-distribution)

How come we can do this for the Normal Distribution and not the Exponential Distribution (or other distributions)? Why is my math wrong here?

In my engineering final project, we need to simulate correlated failure times for machines that statistically depend on one another. I am just trying to understand the mathematical reason why this is so easy for a Multivariate Normal but not for a Multivariate Exponential (or other distributions)?

Answer (score -1):

The Normal distribution has many wonderful properties, and one of the most important is that it is closed under affine transformations.
That is, if $X$ is a $p$-dimensional Gaussian, $A$ is a $n\times p$ matrix, and $b$ an $n$-dimensional vectors, then $AX + b$ is also Gaussian.

This fact guarantees that for *any* mean $\mu$ and *any* valid covariance matrix $\Sigma$ , there exists a normal distribution with that mean and covariance.
And not only that, but it's really easy to construct - if we take $A = \Sigma^{1/2}$ (this can be the positive semidefinite square root, a Cholesky decomposition or any similar matrix square root) and $Z \sim \mathcal{N}_p(0, I)$, then
$$
  AZ + \mu
  \sim \mathcal{N}_p(\mu, \Sigma).
$$

This property is very much not shared by other distributions.
Since affine distributions usually totally screw up the underlying distribution, you need to use other methods to find random vectors whose marginal distributions are what you want and have given covariance matrices, and sometimes it's completely impossible.

Comment: Thanks Damian! But here is my issue - I understand this affine point that you are talking about: linear combinations of normal distributions are also normal - whereas this is not true for non-normal distributions. This is great. But if I write a joint distributions of exponential distributions f(x1,...xn) where each xi ~ exp(lambda_i) ....I am not summing anything. Therefore, why is affine property relevant in determining that a joint distribution of exponential random variables CAN NOT be written the way I did?